# Difference in mapping a network drive by IP or name

Tags: windows, samba

I have a FreeBSD machine running Samba service. I've created a shared folder and put some X86 binaries. I later mapped a network drive on a Windows machine and execute the program. I found an interesting issue that if I map the drive using an IP address, the program executes differently from mapping it using a name.

If I do it using an IP address, the program thinks it's a trial version. But it's completely normal if I map it using the name. I tried different names (hard coded it Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts), and the program behaves the same.

I'm curious about the difference between these methods when mapping a network drive. Apologies if this question is inappropriate here.

Thanks,

Ye-Sheng

Comment: This might not be a Windows issue, but how the software is actually detecting trial/paid version status.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I just couldn't wrap my head around how the software detects this kind of difference.